# Triple value partly random null matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to change that partly random null matrix code:

```
import numpy as np
zero_matrix = np.zeros((10,10), dtype=np.int32)
rng = np.random.default_rng()
x = rng.choice(10, size=5, replace=False)
y = rng.choice(10, size=5, replace=False)
zero_matrix[x,y] = rng.choice(np.arange(1,10), 5)
print(zero_matrix)
```

That output:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 8 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

so the output will be triple value partly random null matrix like that:

```
[[0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [3 1 7] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0]
 [2 2 4] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [9 8 4] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [1 0 9] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [3 5 5] [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0]]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The question seems a bit unclear to me. Do you want simply a 3D array rather a 2D array (containing the same kind of thing)?

Comment: 2D array that each point in it composed from 3 numbers instead of one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to fill the new most-contiguous dimension with random number,
you can just add a new dimension to the created array, generate a bigger array of random numbers (3 times bigger) and set it using a broadcast+reshape.

Here is the resulting code:

```py
import numpy as np
zero_matrix = np.zeros((10,10,3), dtype=np.int32)
rng = np.random.default_rng()
x = rng.choice(10, size=5, replace=False)
y = rng.choice(10, size=5, replace=False)
zero_matrix[x,y,:] = rng.choice(np.arange(1,30), 15).reshape((5,3))
print(zero_matrix)
```

Comment: Thank you Jérôme Richard